# Laravel сохранение действий пользователя за последние полгода

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Делаю интернет-магазин, пользователи будут переходить по рекламе с utm-метками. Каким образом можно сделать отслеживание действий каждого пользователя за последний полгода, т.е. чтобы было понятно, что человек делал перед заказом, по каким ссылкам переходил (контроль utm-меток) и т.д.

Какие есть варианты решения подобного? Сделать отдельную таблицу в БД и записывать туда ID сессии и текущую utm-метку? Или лучше это записывать в сессию/есть какой-либо пакет для отслеживания?

Comment: Есть пакет логов, но он просто пишет переданные метки в базу [spatie/laravel-activitylog](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog)

Comment: Писать действия в сессию перед покупкой, а после, складывать в БД, в случае, если человек ни чего не купит, это так и останется в сессии.